# Issue uploading image to laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get `$request->image->getClientOriginalName()` but it returns

> "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string"

When I call `$request->image`
it returns a string of the image name on my disk like `picture.png`

How to get a file object?!

Comment: Can you share more details about your form?

Comment: @NicoHaase I forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data" on my form declaration .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your form need to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in it. Make sure it looks like this:

```
<form action="your/path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then check that your input has `type="file"`:

```
<input type="file" name="image">
```

Then access your file in your controller via:

```
$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: oh , i have no idea how i forgot (enctype="multipart/form-data")
thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going through this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files); which gives an in depth overview of how handling files from requests work in laravel.

Although you can always do the below:

```
$file = $request->file('photo');
```

**or**

```
$file = $request->photo;
```

I would suggest you going through the documentation and changing the version of laravel as per your needs.